# g++ : should --std option change which STL/stdlib my code uses?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl, g++

I'm confused about whether a recent g++ (say 4.8 or 4.9) should or should not refer to different STLs depending on the --std option selected. Specifically, given the option --std=c++98 vs --std=c++11, shouldn't my code see/use two different STLs in that case? Yet, when I compile with the c++98 option, it seems like I'm still getting the latest STL, which obviously does not work since it uses many things that are c++11 only. I've searched on my system and only found one copy of the STL headers (the c++11 ones). Any clarification on how this is supposed to work is appreciated.

Comment: _"when I compile with the c++98 option, it seems like I'm still getting the latest STL"_ Please provide _evidence_ for your claims. When you say "it seems like", _why_? What do you see? And how did you arrive at your final interpretation of these results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd opened some of those headers then you'd see switches like this one in `bits/stl_algo.h`

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  /**
   *  @brief  Checks that a predicate is true for all the elements
   *          of a sequence.
   *  @ingroup non_mutating_algorithms
   *  @param  __first   An input iterator.
   *  @param  __last    An input iterator.
   *  @param  __pred    A predicate.
   *  @return  True if the check is true, false otherwise.
   *
   *  Returns true if @p __pred is true for each element in the range
   *  @p [__first,__last), and false otherwise.
  */
  template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
    inline bool
    all_of(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
    { return __last == std::find_if_not(__first, __last, __pred); }

...

#endif
```

It'd be nonsensical for an implementation to have to maintain different copies of these files for different `-std` switch settings.

Comment: thanks - this detail helped me understand better. I examined a few headers briefly but did not see the _cplusplus value being checked int the ones I happened to examine. Now it's clear how the source files are essentially internally versioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. *Functionally.*

However, in practice, your implementation may share the same standard library implementation code between them, switching features on and off using macros. GCC does this.

Comment: If you're having a problem, I can't go any further than this general declaration of facts until you tell us what that problem is.